# Blazor WebAssembly Authentication with Open Id failing due to no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, openid, blazor-webassembly

I have a barebones, standalone Blazor WebAssembly project that I am generating via the template in Visual Studio with the options: .Net Core 7, Authentication: Individual Accounts, and none of the check boxes selected (e.g. "Asp.Net Core Hosted, Do not use top-level statements, etc.) but I cannot get the authentication to work with my identity provider.

All I have done is create this project from the above template and added in my OAuth Client's config to wwwroot/appsettings.json.

```
  "Local": {
    "Authority": <myauthorityurl>,
    "ClientId": <myclientid>,
    "ResponseType": "code",
    "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:7202/authentication/login-callback"
  }
```

I also made sure to add the RedirectUri to the oauth config settings (on the oauth side) as https://localhost:7202/authentication/login-callback

When I build and run the project the authentication fails and I see this message in the console:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'https://localhost:7202' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`

The template created by visual studio follows this guide to a T: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio but there is not a single mention of CORS in there.

Thank you in advanced. I understand it may be a little hard to follow this with no code to share but I made sure to generate the template as-is and fill in my config settings.

Comment: Your app should be registered as Single Page Application in Azure AD. How did you register it?

Comment: @juunas I am still in the building/local testing phase. So my app isn't hosted anywhere yet.

Answer (score 0):

[I found this repo and it works well in my side](https://github.com/ChristianWeyer/blazor-wasm-oidc-google-repro). Then I follow the official doc to create new one, add `AllowedHosts` and it project works well. For more details, pls check below.

You should have `"AllowedHosts": "*"` inside your `appsettings.json`. If your project still in development stage, you also need to add it to `appsettings.Development.json` file.

I reproduce the issue and fix it.

```
{
  "Local": {
    "Authority": "https://accounts.google.com/",
    "ClientId": "103****s.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:44370/authentication/logout-callback",
    "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:44370/authentication/login-callback",
    "ResponseType": "id_token"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```